# What's the best way to make a symmetric matrix positive definite?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

Assume that you have a matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and it's symmetric, but it's not positive definite.

What's the best way to turn the matrix $X$ into a positive definite matrix?

I have a suggestion. This suggestion takes a very long time, to increase every diagonal of  $X$ with $+10$ for every iteration.

```
eigenvalues = eig(X);
how_many_negative_eigenvalues = length(find(eigenvalues < 0))
while(how_many_negative_eigenvalues > 0)
  disp('Negative eigenvalues - Use regalarization');
  X = X + 10*eye(size(X));
  eigenvalues = eig(X);
  how_many_negative_eigenvalues = length(find(eigenvalues < 0))
end
disp('No negative eigenvalues - Regalarization done');
```

Can this be done in a faster way?

Comment: If you don't care about the nearness of the result, you could just set it to the identity. If you do, then the best way to to compute the eigendecomposition and modify the eigenvalues directly until they are all positive

Comment: Replace it with the identity matrix? What does it mean to "turn" something into something else? It is the matrix it is. You seem to want an algorithm, but you don't really state what the result of the algorithm should be other than that it is positive definite.

Comment: @whpowell96 Notice that the numbers inside $X$ is very large, so this takes lots of iterations.

Comment: You could replace the entire loop with a single step where you add $\lambda_n + \epsilon$ to every eigenvalue, where $\lambda_n$ is the largest negative eigenvalue. Or just set every non-positive eigenvalue to a positive value $\epsilon$

Comment: @whpowell96 Can you post an answer about it, with an example?

Comment: You should say that the program is written in Matlab language.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. A matrix must have positive eigenvalues if you want it to be positive definite. This will change the matrix's characteristic properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no unique nearest positive definite matrix, but you can make an $\epsilon$-close one. Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix with eigendecomposition $A = U\Lambda U^\top$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_k$, $k=1,\dots,n$. Then the nearest semidefinite matrix is given by $$A_{\geq0} = U\Lambda_{\geq0}U^\top,$$ where the diagonal elements of $\Lambda_{\geq 0}$ are given by $\max(0, \lambda_k)$, $k=1,\dots,n$. To make this construction positive, instead of replacing the eigenvalues with $0$, replace them with a positive number $\epsilon>0$, i.e., $\max(\epsilon, \lambda_k)$. There is no unique nearest positive matrix since you can make $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small.

For example, consider a matrix with eigenvalues $\Lambda = \mathrm{diag}(10,1,0,-10)$. This algorithm replaces these with $\Lambda_{>0} = \mathrm{diag}(10,1,\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Comment: So replace the negative eigenvalues and reconstruct $A$ matrix again?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This sequence of matrices is optimal in the $2$-norm